# How can I get asp.net mvc to recognize decimals in json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

In my .net application I'm using System.Web.Mvc 5.2.3.0. My client is posting up json with the content-type: 'application/json'

```
{From: "EUR", To: "USD", Rate: 0.00001}
```

By the time my controller receives this

```
[HttpPut(), Route("/ExchangeRate/{exchkey}")]
public HttpResponseMessage PutCurrencyExchange(string exchkey, [FromBody()] JObject jsonData)
 {...
```

The JObject's Rate is a string "1E-05".

I've read about custom converters
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters.htm
and contract resolvers
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomContractResolver.htm

I found a number of very old examples for deserializing strongly typed objects. However, I'm hoping I'm just missing a simple configuration change that will allow my controller's JObject to correctly represent the decimal as a decimal.  Note: I recognize that if the client stringifies the value, it will parse it correctly. However, I'm not able to dictate that consumers of my endpoints stringify the values first.

Comment: My mistake... the Rate is coming in as a Double, not a string. The watch window just represented this as 1E-05. Downstream this was being converted to a string and I was trying to convert to a decimal and it was failing. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

I've had better luck with a controller action containing individual parameters rather than from body if you're able to change that

Comment: True, since defining `(string From, string To, double Rate)` as parameters is neater and easier to maintain compared to `[FromBody()] JObject jsonData`.

Comment: I appreciate the contribution. However, this may be an issue in my application for many endpoints where the data posted needs to be in the body.